# Reading Input With Om Next

Tags: clojurescript, om-next

I'm trying to understand how to read state from a text box in `om.next`. As I understand it, we are no longer bound/supposed to use `core.async`.

As a small example, consider writing in a textbox and binding it to a paragraph element, so that the text you enter automatically appears on the screen.

```
(def app-state (atom {:input-text "starting text"}))


 (defn read-fn
   [{:keys [state] :as env} key params]
   (let [st @state]
     (if-let [[_ v] (find st key)]
       {:value v}
       {:value :not-found})))

 (defn mutate-fn
   [{:keys [state] :as env} key {:keys [mytext]}]
   (if (= 'update-text key)
     {:value {:keys [:input-text]}
      :action
      (fn []
        (swap! state assoc :input-text mytext))}
     {:value :not-found}))

(defui RootView
   static om/IQuery
   (query [_]
          [:input-text])
   Object
   (render [_]
           (let [{:keys [input-text]} (om/props _)]
             (dom/div nil
                      (dom/input
                       #js {:id "mybox"
                            :type "text"
                            :value input-text
                            :onChange #(om/transact! _ '[(update-text {:mytext (.-value (gdom/getElement "mybox"))})])
                            })
                      (dom/p nil input-text)))))
```

This doesn't work.

> 1. When firing the onChange event in the `input` form, the quoted expression does not grab the text from the box.
> 2. The first mutation fires and updates, but then subsequent mutations are not fired. Even though the state doesn't changed, should the query read the string from `app-state` and force the text to be the same?

Comment: If you have a ' (single quote) then everything in the following form will just be 'as is'. You need to use a back quote then a ~ (tilde). Fixing that should then grab text from the box.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Okay, so I feel like an idiot, and I'm using the backtick and the escape character. Is this the appropriate way to structure this procedure in om next?

Answer (score 0):

I would make the `:onChange` event look like this:

```
:onChange (fn (_)
            (let [v (.-value (gdom/getElement "mybox"))]
              #(om/transact! this `[(update-text {:mytext ~v})])))
```

Here the value `v` will actually be going through. But also `om/transact!` needs either a component or the reconciler to be passed as its first parameter. Here I'm passing in `this` which will be the root component.